# Specifying font for many Text-elements in Qt QML

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml

I have a widget specified through a QML file. This widget contains a top level`Rectangle` which contains two `Columns`. Each of these `Columns` contains many `Text`-elements. This QML widget is wrapped in a subclass of `QDeclarativeView` in C++.

I want to specify the font for each of these `Text`-elements. Today I do this by specifying top-level properties:

```
property string fontfamily: "Arial"
property bool fontbold: false
property bool fontitalic: false
property int fontpixelsize: 11
property string fontcolor: "White"
```

and bind each `Text`-elements to these properties:

```
Text
{   
    color: fontcolor
    font.family: fontfamily
    font.bold: fontbold
    font.italic: fontitalic
    font.pixelSize: fontpixelsize
    ...
}
```

This isn't very elegant and new fields needs to be added every time I need support for something new (e.g. underlined fonts). I have not been able to declare a property of type `font` and bind to this instead (widget is blank and qmlviewer warns about "expected type after property").

Is there a better way to specify a font for all `Text`-elements?

Note! I'm handwriting the QML files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another possibility is to write a new QML component, that inherits from `Text` an sets some properties by default:

**StyledText.qml**

```qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Text {
    // set default values
    color: "blue"
    font.family: "Arial"
    font.bold: true
    font.italic: true
    font.pixelSize: 12
}
```

**main.qml**

```qml
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
    Row {
        spacing: 10

        Column {
            StyledText {
                text: "Foo1"
            }
            StyledText {
                text: "Bar1"
            }
            StyledText {
                text: "Baz1"
            }
        }

        Column {
            StyledText {
                text: "Foo2"
            }
            StyledText {
                text: "Bar2"
            }
            StyledText {
                text: "Baz2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what is suggested here would be less memory efficient than using Qt.font()

Answer (score 18):

In Qt 5.6 (at least, probably earlier too), you can use `Qt.font()` to dynamically allocate a font object and refer to it elsewhere. So, this works:

```
property font myFont: Qt.font({
    family: fontfamily,
    bold: fontbold,
    italic: fontitalic,
    pixelSize: fontpixelsize
});

Text
{   
    color: fontcolor
    font: parent.myFont
}
```

More info on `Qt.font()` here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#font-method

Comment: You can also expose a QFont from C++ and use it in QML.

Comment: Alas, does not allow you override some properties. All required font properties must be set at once, which may lead to lots of Qt.font's across the application instead of specialising them where needed.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to write a function, that iterates over the `children` of a passed element (for example a `Column`). In this function all the properties can be set:

```qml
import QtQuick 1.0

    Rectangle {
    Row {
        spacing: 10

        Column {
            id: col1

            Text {
                property bool useStyle: true
                text: "Foo1"
            }
            Text {
                property bool useStyle: true
                text: "Bar1"
            }
            Text {
                property bool useStyle: true
                text: "Baz1"
            }
        }

        Column {
            id: col2

            Text {
                property bool useStyle: true
                text: "Foo2"
            }
            Text {
                text: "not styled"
            }
            Text {
                property bool useStyle: true
                text: "Baz2"
            }
        }
    }

    function setTextStyle(parentElement) {
        for (var i = 0; i < parentElement.children.length; ++i) {
            console.log("t", typeof parentElement.children[i]);
            if (parentElement.children[i].useStyle) {  // apply style?
                parentElement.children[i].color = "blue";
                parentElement.children[i].font.family = "Arial"
                parentElement.children[i].font.bold = true;
                parentElement.children[i].font.italic = true;
                parentElement.children[i].font.pixelSize = 12;
            }
        }
    }

    // set style
    Component.onCompleted: {
        setTextStyle(col1);
        setTextStyle(col2);
    }
}
```

Each element, that contains the property `useStyle` that is set to `true`, gets styled. This is shorter, than assigning the style manually, but you can still define which elements should get styled or not.

Answer (score 2):

Necro posting, but I feel it's still missing an up-to-date solution.
`FontMetrics` will do the trick without using `Qt.font()`. You can declare it in your parent item or in a `Singleton` type, and then you can bind the property to it.

Here there's an example

```
Item {
  id: root
    
  FontMetrics {
    id: fontMetrics
    font.family: "Arial"
    font.pixelSize: 24
  }
    
  property alias font: fontMetrics.font
    
  Text { font: root.font }
  Text { font: root.font }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some useful workarounds here, but I'm stuck being able to define some base fonts while still being able to specify details later, for more than a few fonts. In particular, because:

1. `FontLoader` sets the same `name` for every font of the same family. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65052179/3697870)
2. If `Qt.font()` (or `FontMetrics`) is used, it's all or nothing for the `font` property.
3. Defining new `Text` Components requires one file per font. Update: maybe [not true since 5.15](https://www.qt.io/blog/new-qml-language-features-in-qt-5.15).
4. Triggering a `function` is difficult to manage effectively across a whole application.

I think there's room for one more solution:

In my `main.qml` I used one `FontLoader` per font file, but only bothered setting an `id` when the family changes:

```
FontLoader { source: "qrc:/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-Bk.otf";     id: flAvantGarde;   }
FontLoader { source: "qrc:/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-BkObl.otf";                      }
FontLoader { source: "qrc:/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-BoldCn.otf";                     }
FontLoader { source: "qrc:/fonts/ITCAvantGardeStd-Md.otf";                         }
FontLoader { source: "qrc:/fonts/ADAM.CG PRO.otf";             id: flAdam;         }
```

and then, and here's the significant part, defined one `property var` per base font like so:

```
property var fontAgBk:      { "family": flAvantGarde.name, "styleName": "Book" }
property var fontAgBkObl:   { "family": flAvantGarde.name, "styleName": "Book Oblique" }
property var fontAgBoldCn:  { "family": flAvantGarde.name, "styleName": "Bold Condensed" }
property var fontAgMd:      { "family": flAvantGarde.name, "styleName": "Medium" }
property var fontAdam:      { "family": flAdam.name }
```

The `var` is key being able to specify a dictionary that can be defined once, but pulled apart later.

Elsewhere in any `qml`, I can do something like:

```
Text {
    id: myText
    color: "#123456"
    font.family: fontBoldCn.family
    font.styleName: fontBoldCn.styleName
    font.pixelSize: 24
    font.letterSpacing: 5
}
```

Still requires some repetitive code, but at least the magic strings are only defined once.