# QML: How to retrieve a default font object?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML `Item` with some `Text` fields in it, which should have all the same font. Do achieve this i introduce a new property `myFont` of type `font`. Do initialize this property I use the `Qt.font` function, which creates a font object. But I have to specify at least one property (either `family` or `pointSize`).

My Question is now: How can I retrieve the default font for the `myFont` property?
If I create only a `Text{}` item, it has already a default font attached, how can I get the same font for the `myFont` property? (Meanwhile I use a hidden `Text` field and create an alias to it's `font` property, but I want a better solution).

```
Item {
 property font myFont: Qt.font({pointSize: 10})
 Text {
  id: header
  font: myFont
  text: "My Header"
 }
 Text {
  id: subject
  font: myFont
  text: "My Subject"
 }
 Text {
  id: message
  font: myFont
  text: "Some meassage!"
 }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `property font myFont: header.font`? And remove the default `font` binding from `header`?

Comment: Actually the Text fields reside inside a ListView Delegate, so this was my first attempt, but it didn't work (or I can't figure out how).

Comment: You should create your own object type (i.e. `MyText`  that declares a `Text`) with the font you need to use. Then use `MyText` instead of `Text`.

Comment: How should that help to set a common font from outside to a listview delegate?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, I've digged into Qt source code. 
And it turns out that Qt uses a registered private TextSingleton which is defined (Qt 5.6) as:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.2
Text {
}
```

The font property of various qml controls is initialized:

```
font: TextSingleton.font
```

Digging further into C++ code reveals that for the `Text` item, the `font` property is a default initialized `QFont`, which gives the `QFont` object retrieved from `QGuiApplication::font()`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the right way to solve this is to create your own object type with the font you need to use.

In the following example, the new object would be `MyText.qml`. I don't know your whole code, but I suppose you have a `ListView` with the delegate you posted in your question.

**MyText.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    font: Qt.font({pointSize: 10})
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: myModel
        ListElement {
            header: "header xxx"
            subject: "subject xxx"
            message: "message xxx"
        }
        ListElement {
            header: "header yyy"
            subject: "subject yyy"
            message: "message yyy"
        }
        ListElement {
            header: "header zzz"
            subject: "subject zzz"
            message: "message zzz"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: myModel
        delegate: Item {
            width: 300; height: 80
            Column {
                MyText {
                    id: myheader
                    text: header  + " - family: " + font.family  + " size: " + font.pointSize
                }
                MyText {
                    id: mysubject
                    text: subject  + " - family: " + font.family + " size: " + font.pointSize
                }
                MyText {
                    id: mymessage
                    text: message  + " - family: " + font.family + " size: " + font.pointSize
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, but is not configurable, which was the main reason, why I like to declare a font property.
My ListView is in a separte component which can be placed on a form and there I like to set the font to all listview items.

`MainForm {
   MyComponentWithAListView {
    font: Qt.font({family:"Arial", pointSize: 12})
   }
}
`

Comment: @jonjonas68 Please, update your question with your requirements. Probably, what you need are bindings or some signal/slots to update the font when it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741573/specifying-font-for-many-text-elements-in-qt-qml/68352363#68352363), FontMetrics is the way to go since it's configurable and  without using Qt.font(). You can declare it in your parent item or in a SIngleton type and the you can bind the property to it.

Here there's an example

```
Item {
id: root

FontMetrics {
    id: fontMetrics
    font.family: "Arial"
    font.pixelSize: 24
}

property alias font: fontMetrics.font

Text { font: root.font }
Text { font: root.font }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the default font in QML with `Qt.application.font`.

You can get and set this font in C++ using

```cpp
QFont font = QApplication::font();
font.setPointSize(12); //make various other changes or get a completely new QFont
QApplication::setFont(font);
```