# QML error "Unknown component. (M300)" but the code works

Tags: qml

I want to use a custom font in a QML application, and to not have to specify it in every text field, I use a component as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750188/788824).

I have a `DefaultText.qml` under a `styles` prefix in my `qml.qrc`, which resides in the folder `styles`.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Text {
    color: "black"
    font.family: myCustomFont.name
    font.bold: false
    font.italic: false
    font.pixelSize: 14
}
```

I use it, among other places, in a qml named `PanelRight.qml`, under the prefix `Panels` in the folder `widgets`. It's all under the same `qml.qrc`.

```
import "qrc:/styles/styles"

Item
{
    // ...
    DefaultText { text: "xyz" }
}
```

Interestingly, `DefaultText` is underlined as an error, with the message **"Unknown component. (M300)"**. However, I can successfully compile and run my application, and the custom font is displayed correctly. However, it's annoying that I have a long list of errors (I intend to use it in a lot of places) and that autocomplete doesn't work.

I searched the Qt forums, this problem was mentioned there in case of custom plugins, which I don't use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add relative path of `DefaultText.qml` in `PanelRight.qml` file as

```
import "../styles"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import QtQuick.Controls.Material
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32393032)