# QML FontLoader.name confusion

Tags: qt, fonts, qml, loader

I downloaded from Google Fonts two .ttf files on my project folder:

1. Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf
2. Montserrat-Black.ttf

I set propperly the .qrc file in order to contain both of them.

Suppose I have the next .qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0

Rectangle{
        id: rectangle
        height: 500
        width: 700
          Column{
              FontLoader { id: myCustomFont1; source: "../Fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraLight.ttf" }
              FontLoader { id: myCustomFont2; source: "../Fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Black.ttf" }
              Text{
                  ...
                  text: "Qt for python"
                  font.family: myCustomFont1.name
                  ...
              }
              Text{
                  ...
                  text: "Qt for c++"
                  font.family: myCustomFont2.name
                  ...
              }
          }
        
}
```

The problem is that the `myCustomFont1.name` and the `myCustomFont2.name` are the same, namely "Montserrat" and I don't have any solution to make distinction between them.
Therefore even if I specified the correct FontLoader-s id-s, the second text will have the same font.family like the first text.
Could be possible to solve this problem somehow?

Comment: Does setting `font.weight` work for you?

Comment: For this particular fonts doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution, but a workaround that should work. There's an open-source font editor called [FontForge](https://fontforge.org) that you can use to change the names that Qt reads. Open the font files in question and then open the menu `Element->Font Info`. That opens a dialog with multiple tabs on the left. The first tab should be `PS Names`. This should list several fields including `Fontname` and `Family Name`. You should be able to edit those to whatever you want. Then close that dialog and use `File->Generate Fonts` to regenerate the .ttf files.

Comment: Well, thx for this app. I installed it on my Mac and I changed those fields as per your instructions. But now the FontLoader name is absolutely blank. Doesn't have any name ...

Comment: Not sure why that would be. I haven’t had that problem when I’ve done it.

Comment: Great. Hope it works until you find a better solution.

Comment: After I played around with the new FontForge app I realized where should be made the modification: should navigate such as:  ```File->Element->Font Info``` as you said and there shouldn't touch anything in ```PS Names``` but rather should go in ```TTF Names``` and in that particular table if exists the row  _Preferred Family_, should modify the name as per desire. If not, should create  a new row named like that and fill there the new desired _Font Name_. Thanks again. I will close the question considering good enough your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is perplexing and a common source of frustration. It turns out that the `name` property actually specifies the `family`, which as you've discovered, is the same for these font files.

What distinguishes them is actually the `styleName`.

Try opening the font file in a font viewer like "Font Book" or "FontForge" to get the exact `styleName` - you'll need to specify it with a string.

Then specify the additional property:

```
          Text{
              ...
              text: "Qt for python"
              font.family: myCustomFont1.name //or myCustomFont2.name, it doesn't matter.
              font.styleName: "Extra Light"
              ...
          }
          Text{
              ...
              text: "Qt for c++"
              font.family: myCustomFont2.name
              font.styleName: "Black"
              ...
          }
```

I've found `styleName` far more predictable than combinations of `weight` or `style` or `bold`. And that way you can work with fonts that follow the canonical naming conventions rather than hacking their Family Name to suit QML.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day on an issue where text would be rendered garbled (selecting wrong glyphs, so readable but wrong letters)