# QML set font capitalization

Tags: qt, qml

I'm writing a reusable font property, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487505/reusable-font-properties-in-qml) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741573/specifying-font-for-many-text-elements-in-qt-qml).
Here's my property

```
property font button2: Qt.font({
    family: defaultFont.name,
    styleName: "Bold",
    pointSize: 16
})
```

and here it how I use it, and it works fine

```
    Text {
        text: "button"
        font: MyFont.button2
    }
```

Now I would add the capitalization but adding it to the property like this

```
property font button2: Qt.font({
    family: defaultFont.name,
    styleName: "Bold",
    capitalization: "AllUppercase",
    pointSize: 16
})
```

It does not have effect at all. If I add it in the text component instead

```
    Text {
        text: "button"
        font: MyFont.button2
        font.capitalization: Font.AllUppercase
    }
```

it gives me a *"Property has already been assigned a value"* error.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the capitalization then you must use it in Component.onCompleted:

```
Text {
    text: "button"
    font: MyFont.button2
    // font.capitalization: Font.AllUppercase
    Component.onCompleted: font.capitalization = Font.AllUppercase
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I had the impression it was a workaround and not the proper way to do that. There is actually no other way?

Comment: @Moia No, there is no way. Realize your logic: The binding is not sequential, that is, the property on the "N" line is not executed before the "N + 1" line, it may or may not.

Comment: Soo are you saying I can't either putting it inside the Qt.font() function because the binding should happen after the object is constructed?